# SQL integer variable

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, sql-update

I'm making this UPDATE string for my acces 2007 database using excel

```
conn.Execute ("UPDATE newEmployees Set Firstname = 'testname1' Where Id = sID;")
```

sID is a number, but when I use it like this or like " & sID & " I get an error. On the other hand if I just write a number Where Id = 46 - It works just fine.

So my question is, how do I make an update string in SQL with a number variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
conn.Execute ("UPDATE newEmployees Set Firstname = 'testname1' Where Id=" & sID)
```